# Data is modified when closing or canceling a settings dialog - wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, datatemplate

*This is what I want to achieve*: On my application, I open a new window when clicking a certain button. This window is a dialog to select some application settings. I want to accept those changes when the user presses OK, and discard them if the user closes the dialog or presses Cancel.

The structure of this dialog is a tree view to select the settings page, and a frame that changes its content depending on the treeViewItem selected. In one of the settings page, I have a ListView with items (which are added on runtime). Those items is a custom class called CustomListViewItems with two properties: Name and Number. This CustomListViewItems items are shown in the ListView as a IntegerUpDown to select the Number and a TextBlock for the Name. This is done with DataTemplate and Binding the properties as this code shows:

```
<ListView Margin="5, 3, 5, 3" Grid.Row="1" Name="listView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="150" Width="300">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <xctk:IntegerUpDown Minimum="0" Maximum="9" Value="{Binding Number}"></xctk:IntegerUpDown> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the code-behind, I have an ObservableCollection of type CustomListViewItems as a member variable which holds the items in the list view. (Which is linked with the ItemsSource List view on the creation of the page. Once those items are listed on the ListView, their properties can be modified by changing the value of the IntegerUpDown.

There is a Preference.cs class which holds the settings. This class, has a List of type CustomListViewItems as a member variable and this is written only after the user presses OK on the PreferenceDialog. If I place a breakpoint on the SetPreferences and GetPreferences methods of Preference.cs, I verify that the the GetPreferences breaks every time that the PreferenceDialog is created (as expected, because the dialog shows on creation the current preferences), and the **SetPreferences breaks every time that the PreferenceDialog is closed with the OK button but not with the Cancel or close** (which ALSO is as expected, but the strange thing here is that when I open the Settings Dialog again after closing it with Cancel or close, the preferences returned by Preferences.cs are modified!!). I don´t save this preferences but somehow they are saved ( and I am guessing that maybe it´s due to the Binding ).

Here the code-behind that corresponds to the btnDialogOk_Click:

```
private void btnDialogOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((PreferencesPage1)mPreferencesPages[0]).AcceptPreferences())
    {
        var customItems = ((PreferencesPage1)mPreferencesPages[0]).GetItems();
        mPreferences.ClearcustomItems();
        mPreferences.SetcustomItems(customItems);

        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Number must be unique on its own category", "Error",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

My Dialog is created by the MainUserControl, which holds the OpenPreferences button. This is the peace of code that creates the dialog:

```
private void OpenPreferencesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PreferencesDialog preferencesDialog = new PreferencesDialog(mPreferences);

        preferencesDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I've tried to fixed this creating a "backup" list of CustomListViewItems just after opening and restoring the preferences on cancel, but ALSO the backup list of CustomListViewItems items is modified. Can anyone address me on how to fix this? Maybe I am not getting the concept of binding correctly and I am binding something wrong.

Comment: Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: why are you not showing the code in the .cs file that or which pertains to the `Ok, Cancel, || Close`..?

Comment: Cancel and close functions are empty. I will post the code that pertains to the Ok function. (Edited on my post). thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: I will post a small snippet of what you could do if you are displaying a Dialog to get users Response back

Comment: Thanks! Just editted to show you the ok function :)

Comment: where are you declaring the `DialogResult variable` ? have you done a google search on `C# MSDN DialogResult` there are plenty of good working examples on how you need to setup your method to handle the user response

Comment: Is your dialog custom dialog?

Comment: yes. it is a custom dialog

Answer (score 0):

if you want to code for `Ok Close, and Cancel buttons` you want to setup your Dialog something like this

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Do you want to save changes?", "Some Name for your Popup Dialog"), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //do work
}
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    //...
}
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi. I will edit my question so I add the piece of code that sets up the Dialog.

Comment: The "do work" is in the btnDialogOk_Click function of the Dialog itself. Shall I remove it from there and do it in the MainUserControl, which creates the dialog?